# Retrieve byte[] in android from JSON webservice

Tags: java, android, arrays, rest, blob

I successfully stored image in database  in BLOB format.

Data type for image in webservices model class  is byte [].

**Web service:**

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("login")
public User Login(User input) {
```

**Request:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "password": "******",
        "username": "haris",
        "image": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAizDMizDMizDMizDMizDMizDMizDMizDMizDMizDMiz/JPL/AOc68RGNGkMYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
    }
]
```

We can see that the json service makes conversion to String, byte [] is converted into a String.

I tried to make the conversion from the String to byte [], but for result I can't see any picture data.

```
byte [] byteData = new byte[imageData().length()];
            
imageView.setImageBitmap(getImage(byteData));


public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
```

Comment: That looks like Base64 encoding using 64=2^6 chars A-Za-z-9/+ to encode 6 bits, needing 4 chars for 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(img, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
if (bitmap != null) {
Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 90, 100, true));
}
```